# Why does Erlang runtime (or RabbitMQ) listen on a random UDP port?

Tags: rabbitmq

After an update to RabbitMQ 3.7.8 and Erlange 21.1 (centOS 6 server) netstat shows that beam.smp is listening on a random UDP port on all interfaces:

```
~$ sudo netstat -pnul | grep beam
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:45224          0.0.0.0:*             7320/beam.smp
```

That port is changing with every restart and is not closed when stopping the app but changes when starting it back:

```
~$ sudo rabbitmqctl stop_app
Stopping rabbit application on node rabbit@host ...
~$ sudo netstat -pnul | grep beam
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:45224          0.0.0.0:*             7320/beam.smp
~$ sudo rabbitmqctl start_app
Starting node rabbit@host ...
 completed with 7 plugins.
~$ sudo netstat -pnul | grep beam
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:51001          0.0.0.0:*             7320/beam.smp
```

- Disabling all plugins does not change this behaviour so I guess this is not plugin related.
- tcpdump does not show any activity on this port.
- I can't find any trace of this in the RabbitMQ's documentation.
- I can't find anything related to this on the Internet
- grepping the code of "rabbitmq-server" for "udp" does not give much info

The main question is what is this port used for?
As a corollary, is it possible to configure this?

Comment: Thank you for reporting this. It's not a security issue as nothing is listening on the port. We will see if we can avoid this behavior - https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/1718

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me it's a port bound by the syslog_logger module, coming from this RabbitMQ dependency:

https://github.com/schlagert/syslog

Looks like it is by default is started on the RabbitMQ node and when it starts up it binds to a random port:

The dependency: 
https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/c1fb658ce13ae7f14919bd784eddd3dc77ab5144/Makefile#L139

The line where the port is opened: 
https://github.com/schlagert/syslog/blob/ac8b9eecd593b8cc5a8b1de332d5d7d874e25aa9/src/syslog_logger.erl#L323-L323

According to the docs this feature is default disabled, but the Erlang application is started. I guess it would be better if the application is not started when it is disabled.

If you want to verify it for yourself, you can do this:

Start a remote shell into the Rabbit Erlang VM:

```
% Start remote console
erl -sname test -remsh rabbit@$HOSTNAME
% Get all the port infos from the Erlang VM
PortInfos = lists:map(fun erlang:port_info/1, erlang:ports()).
% print the result
rp(PortInfos).
% Investigate the list for one which has the {name, udp_inet} line
% something like this: 
 [{name,"udp_inet"},
  {links,[<0.77.0>]},
  {id,9568},
  {connected,<0.77.0>},
  {input,0},
  {output,0},
  {os_pid,undefined}]
% And from this you can get the linked process, and see that it is a syslog_logger process
rp(erlang:process_info(erlang:list_to_pid("<0.77.0>"))).

% The result will be something like this
[{registered_name,syslog_logger},
 {current_function,{gen_server,loop,7}},
 {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}},
 {status,waiting},
 {message_queue_len,0},
 {messages,[]},
 {links,[#Port<0.1196>,<0.76.0>]},
 {dictionary,[{'$initial_call',{syslog_logger,init,1}},
              {'$ancestors',[<0.76.0>,<0.75.0>]}]},
 {trap_exit,false},
 ......]
```

You can see the `$initial_call` part, it tells you which module is it.

Currently it doesn't look like that this behaviour can be controlled. 
The code only does sending, no receiving is implemented in the module as I can see.

Comment: Thank you for the analysis. Opening that port is required to send UDP packets to a syslog server, but it shouldn't be opened unless the module is in use. We'll see if this can be addressed - https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/1718

Comment: Thanks for the analysis, it's really useful. The firewall is on drop policy so no real security threat here. Thanks @LukeBakken for the bug report.

Comment: In addition, sending data to that port has no effect as it is dropped anyway.